# How to print Binary Search Tree in specific format C++

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, binary-search-tree

I have to read data from the file and construct a binary search tree from 
the values in the order they are read. Thus; the first number read will be the root of the tree. I must attempt to store the numbers in an array.
When I have read the last value into the BST, I need to conduct an in‐order traversal to output first 10 values in ascending order and Print them 10 to a line in a 5‐character wide field. .

My output is fine and printing all integers in ascending order but I want to print 10 integers in one line. I am stuck here. Can anybody help me figure this one out ?

My Code:

```
 struct Node
 {
    int key;
    Node *left, *right;
 };

 int NumNodes = 0;
 const int SIZE = 100;
 Node data[SIZE];

 Node* nNode(int value)
 {
    Node* temp = &data[NumNodes++];
    temp->key  = value;                  
    temp->left = temp->right = NULL; 
    return temp;
 }
      void inorder(Node *root)
{
if (root != NULL)
{
    inorder(root->left); 
    cout << root->key << setw(5) ;
    inorder(root->right);
}
Node* insert(Node* node, int key)
{
    if (node == NULL)
{
    return nNode(key);
}
if (key < node->key)
{
    node->left  = insert(node->left, key);
}
else if (key > node->key)
{
    node->right = insert(node->right, key);   
}
return node;
}

int main()
{
 int c,val,i=0;
string fileName;

Node *root = NULL;

ifstream infile;
cout << "Please enter the name of the file to open :";
cin >> fileName;                                                  // asks user to input filename
infile.open(fileName.c_str());                                    // opens file
if(!infile)
{
    cerr << "An eror occurred while openieng the file.";
    exit(1);
}

while(!infile.eof()){
    infile >> val;
    data[i].key = val;
    c=data[i].key; 

    root = insert(root, c);

    i++;        

}
infile.close();

inorder(root);


return 0;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at this line and the lines after it. `if(NumNodes == SIZE)`  Are you missing braces? You are if you don't want that exit to be unconditional. You also don't want to use `eof` like you are. `while(infile >> val) { ... }` is the correct way to read items from a file.

Comment: What is in the input file?  Should be easy to debug.

Comment: The program contains a bug, and in order to fix the bug you first have to find it, via debugging.  You can do that either by using your IDE's debugger, or (if you don't have a debugger handy) you can put statements like `cout << __LINE__ << std::endl;` at various places and re-run your program until you find the line that causes the crash (by seeing which is the last line number to be printed out).  Once you know which line of code is causing the crash, you'll need to examine that line to figure out why -- most likely it is trying to dereference a NULL or otherwise invalid pointer.

Comment: `root = insert(root,val);` there is issue with this line. But what is the issue?

Comment: You should really ask a different question rather than morphing this one into three so far. Your `inorder` function is not included in your example, so it's hard to give advice about code that cannot be seen. Perhaps read some documentation about what `%` does.

Comment: I cannot as advised by the team. Also, my `inorder` is already included in the function

Comment: I have already included `inorder` but I am trying to print out 10 numbers in each line that's the issue.

Comment: My question is already getting low rating because of posting two question with same title that's why I have to change the title to get it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void inorder(Node *root)
{
static int n=0;         
if (root != NULL)
{
    inorder(root->left);
    cout << setw(5) << root->key;  
    if(n%10==9)cout << endl;
    n++;
    inorder(root->right);

}
}
```

Comment: `static int n` is not a good idea! If you call the function more than once, it won't split line correctly if the previous print has not a multiple of 10 items.

Comment: or else can declare int i as globAL, it will work then

Comment: While it could work if `inorder` in called from a single thread only, it still a poor design as the function does too much. At the very least, traversal and action executed on each item should be independent.